# How to stop scrolling of header of UITableView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Can I stop table header view from scrolling?

Comment: "table header view" ? a table only contains UITableCells

Comment: Antwan, you're wrong. A UITableView can contain a header and a footer view. And also separate views for section headers and footers too. Do your research ;)

Comment: Yeah, I want to do this as well! I suppose the easiest way to do it would be to put the header view in the first cell of each section. Then make that particular row ~10 points taller.

Comment: For section headers you need to implement the UITableView delegate method viewForHeaderInSection:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table header view is attached to the table and is within the content view of the table's internal scroll view. You can't stop it from scrolling.

You may be able to get the effect by making your table view slightly less tall and placing a view above it as a sibling rather than a child.

This will require you to implement the controller as a UIViewController rather than a UITableViewController though so that the view property isn't the table itself.