# Fixed row in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to implement a UITableView / UITableViewController which has a fixed row on top - to search/add contacts. I probably could add an UIView first and an UITableView after to achieve this - I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this. Does anyone know a better solution here ?

what it should look like (e.g. whatsapp)
[image]

Comment: just add a custom `UIView` above the table

Comment: I did now, was best solution here I think.

Comment: Does your table consist of a single section? If it does I have a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could add an UIView first and an UITableView after for fixing your top row,  this is the right solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a view as `headerView` of the table view. Have a look at the docs from Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableHeaderView

```
UIView *searchContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchContainer;
```

Comment: According http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834640/how-to-stop-scrolling-of-header-of-uitableview, it's not possible to make tableHeaderView static so it doesn't scroll.

Comment: You are right, didn't read that in your question. Then, as others pointed out add a view above your table view. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Yes ofcourse,
Take 2 tableviewCell.
make 1 static and fill up with information u want in its Class file,
make another dynamic(basically the reuseable id) and work on it,in the tableviewController.

Position the cells accordingly in the storyboard before u start coding.